# Where should I define properties in sonar-groovy?

Tags: jenkins, grails, groovy, sonarqube, codenarc

I went through the https://github.com/pmayweg/sonar-groovy

In README.md it specified few properties need to mention, but I am not able to identify where and in which file I have to mention them.

Actual information defined in `pmayweg/sonar-groovy/README.md`:

> CodeNarc It is possible to reuse a previously generated report from CodeNarc by setting the `sonar.groovy.codenarc.reportPaths` property.
>
> Groovy File Suffixes It is possible to define multiple groovy file suffixes to be recognized by setting the `sonar.groovy.file.suffixes` property. Note that by default, only files having .groovythe  as extension will be analyzed.
>
> Unit Tests Execution Reports Import unit tests execution reports (JUnit XML format) by setting the `sonar.junit.reportsPath property`. Default location is target/surefire-reports.
>
> JaCoCo and Binaries The groovy plugin requires access to source binaries when analyzing JaCoCo reports. Consequently, property `sonar.groovy.binaries` has to be configured for the analysis (comma-separated paths to binary folders). For Maven and gradle projects, the property is automatically set.

Comment: Take a look at [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find out

sonar-scanner.properties in sonar-scanner/conf or
sonar-project.properties in your project.